# How do I pass parameters via url in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a parameter to my view, but I keep getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /pay/how

Reverse for 'pay_summary' with arguments '(False,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pay/summary/$']
```

`/pay/how` is the current view that I'm at. (that is the current template that that view is returning).

urls.py

```
url(r'^pay/summary/$', views.pay_summary, name='pay_summary')
```

views.py

```
def pay_summary(req, option):
    if option:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
    ....
```

template

```
<a href="{% url 'pay_summary' False %}">my link</a>
```

**EDIT**

I want the view should accept a POST request, not GET.

Comment: It's not clear what you want the url tag to return. Do you want the `False` to be part of the url e.g. `/pay/summary/False/` or a GET parameter e.g. `/pay/summary/?value=False`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

Comment: You are missing 2 things: 1. Parameter in the url definition, 2. The parameter needs to be an integer or a string, but not python boolean type(because url is a string).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to define a variable on the url. For example:

```
url(r'^pay/summary/(?P<value>\d+)/$', views.pay_summary, name='pay_summary')),
```

In this case you would be able to call `pay/summary/0`

It could be a string true/false by replacing `\d+` to `\s+`, but you would need to interpret the string, which is not the best.

You can then use:

```
<a href="{% url 'pay_summary' value=0 %}">my link</a>
```

Comment: Ty that worked. Btw is there a way to do this without the /0 showing in the url?

Comment: You have three ways to pass arguments: 1) Like in the answer, 2) with GET parameters (pay/summary?value=0), with POST parameters (Using forms). Only form with no show the value on the URL, but are not useful for links.

Comment: I think it should be a capital 'S' rather than lower case for a string

Comment: I did not use Django since a very long time. Do you have by chance a reference in the doc so that I can update the answer? Otherwise I will just update to tell it is outdated.

Answer (score 26):

To add to the accepted answer, in Django 2.0 the url syntax has changed:

```
path('<int:key_id>/', views.myview, name='myname')
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<key_id>[0-9])/$', views.myview, name='myname')
```