# How to pass parameter in url?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a task in which in have to create view.py, template, url.py and model.py in django, In which I have four Button D1, D2, D3, D4 in template.
When I click on D1 it should redirect me to a page whose link is:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/test/**D1**`

And while clicking on D2 link redirects me one same page and link is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/test/**D2**`

Similarly while clicking on D2 and D3 links are
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/test/**D3**` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/test/**D4**`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass parameters via url in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567808/how-do-i-pass-parameters-via-url-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters in Django URLs like this

`path('test/<int:post_id>',views.index, name='index'),`

Here **post_id** is the parameter you can use yours.

`<int:>` is for integers and `<str:>` is for strings

Comment: Also, You can accept the same variable in your view along with your request parameter as:
`SomeViewName(request, post_id):`