# Django: pass some paremeter to view in Django urls

Tags: django

I want to pass some string for some urls to my views in django

Suppose i have

```
path('someurl/', someview , name='someurl'),
```

I want to pass some string to someview, when this url is called so is this possible

```
path('someurl/', someview(somevar="test") , name='someurl'),
```

and then i have the view

```
def someview(request, somevar):
    access somevar here
```

Is this possible in Django urls.

Comment: it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to accept parameter from the client, update your path as below:

```
path('someurl/<str:somevar>/', someview , name='someurl')
```

And view now can accept extra parameter:

```
def someview(request, somevar):
    # now you can use somevar
```

With this definition, if client requests `somevar/urlparam/`, `"urlparam"` will be passed to you view function.

Otherwise if you want to provide your own argument, Django doesn't provide the way to do it directly in url definition. But, since that variable is your own one, why don't assign (or compute) that in view? I mean:

```
def someview(request):
    somevar = "test"  # or you may call some function for dynamic assignment
    # now somevar exists in this scope, so you can use it as you want
```

Comment: Most probably you'll get ***`TypeError: someview() got an unexpected keyword argument 'somevar'`***

Comment: @JPG edited my answer for preventing ambiguity

Comment: thanks for the reply. Clear that its not possible

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. You need to define those parameters in the [url as pseudo path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/):

```
path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
```

There is also an option to use request.GET and request.POST to access the optional [parameters list in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162625/django-request-get-parameters):

```
 request.POST.get('<par name here>','<default value here>')
 request.GET.get('<par name here>','<default value here>')
```

Another thing you may find useful is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567808/how-do-i-pass-parameters-via-url-in-django).